# Does NonValidatingLoginModule support multi-users login?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I started with the sample FormBasedAuthenticationProject which uses NonValidatingLoginModule.

I launched the app and login as testUserA.  Works fine.   Then I launched another new browser window intended to login as testUserB.   But the app thinks I am logged in already and the WL.Server.getActiveUser returns testUserA.   Just wonder does WL.Server support multiple users logged in concurrently?

Comment: It probably does, but maybe not with the same cookie. Try using two different browsers (not just different windows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Browser's windows or tabs share cookies amongst themselves, which is why you say you are already logged-in after launching the web app in a new browser's window. For example, you can login to Facebook in window A, then open window B and you will still be logged in.

If you will test this in a device, this will not happen to you.
To "overcome" this "limitation" when testing in browser, you can:

1. Clear cookies before trying in window B
2. Try in incognito mode
3. Try in a different browser. For example, Safari and Chrome.